# How to fetch link from graphQl rich text and show it in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js

```
import React from "react";
import Link from'next/link';

import styles from "./blogStyles/PostDetail.module.css";

const PostDetail = ({ post }) => {
  const getContentFragment = (index, text, obj, type, link) => {
    let modifiedText = text;
    let modifiedLink = link;
    if (obj) {
      if (obj.bold) {
        modifiedText = <b key={index}>{text}</b>;
      }

      if (obj.italic) {
        modifiedText = <em key={index}>{text}</em>;
      }

      if (obj.underline) {
        modifiedText = <u key={index}>{text}</u>;
      }

      if (obj.link) {
        modifiedLink = <Link key={index}>{text}</Link>;
      }
    }

    switch (type) {
      case "heading-three":
        return (
          <h3 key={index}>
            {modifiedText.map((item, i) => (
              <React.Fragment key={i}>{item}</React.Fragment>
            ))}
          </h3>
        );
      case "paragraph":
        return (
          <p key={index}>
            {modifiedText.map((item, i) => (
              <React.Fragment key={i}>{item}</React.Fragment>
            ))}
          </p>
        );
      case "heading-four":
        return (
          <h4 key={index}>
            {modifiedText.map((item, i) => (
              <React.Fragment key={i}>{item}</React.Fragment>
            ))}
          </h4>
        );
      default:
        return modifiedText;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.PostDetail}>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      <div className={styles.featuredFirst}>
        <img src={post.featuredImage.url} alt="" className={styles.postDetailImage}/>
        <p>{post.excerpt}</p>
      </div>
      <img src={post.inPostPhoto[0].url} alt="" className={styles.inPostPhoto}/>
      <div className={styles.authorDate}>
        <h3>Written by : {post.author.name}</h3>
        <h3>Written on : {moment(post.createdAt).format("MMM  DD,  YYYY")}</h3>
        <h3>Categories: {post.categories[0].name}</h3>
      </div>
        {post.content.raw.children.map((typeObj, index) => {
          const children = typeObj.children.map((item, itemIndex) =>
            getContentFragment(itemIndex, item.text, item)
          );

          return getContentFragment(index, children, typeObj, typeObj.type);
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostDetail;
```

Here I have fetched **bold**, *italic* and underlined characters from graphQl rich text. I initiated a RICH TEXT in my graphQl schema. I have written this content in a RICH TEXT format.
I am able to get the text as **bold** , *italic* and underlined how I marked it in the text box > graphQl content.

But I wanted to display hyperlinks to a particular url. I could intiate the link in the textbox but it is not able to show it on my web page! Should I make some changes to this code? Is there any way to get links from text box and their text from graphQl and show it on the web page?

This might be a bit confusing. Any responses would be highly appreciated!